# wordpress theme - links (relative or hardcoded)

Tags: wordpress

I am using a wordpress theme and am confused about links to other pages.
there are places where I can add a link to an existing button but I am not sure whether the link should be hardcoded or not.

e.g.
www.mysite/wordpress/?page=123

or

?page=123

Also if I have to hardcode it, should I be using http*s*://??

This is not HTML, its like a textbox where you can add a link for a button, I guess the theme provides it.

Here is an image which shows how you can add a link to a button, it askes for a link, I would want to link to my contact page, what should i enter here?

[image]

Apologies this is all new to me.

Comment: try it out, and see what happens..

Comment: you should be able to do both - but ?page=123 is a shitty link tho - I would change that structure in permalinks settings

Comment: If you’re talking about links that you typed in using the WYSIWYG editor, I would definitely leave off the protocol and domain, because that makes it much easier if you decide to change your domain, since the browser will just use the current protocol and domain when navigating. If you’re talking about something generated via PHP, then I have no idea.

Comment: what should the permalinks structure be?

Comment: ok I changed the permalinks to post name

Comment: +1 for permalinks.  You're simply asking if you should use a qualified URL or a relative path.  The short answer is you can use either.  As for protocol (HTTP or HTTPS), if you're using one of those everywhere else on the site then you should use it in the full URL. If you're using relative paths, it'll be inherited.

Answer (score 0):

As i know you can hardcode it. Like in Title

I use this code for

```
<?php the_title();?><?php the_permalink();?>
```

it will link to the page according to the title of the page/posts.
hope this helps

Comment: but this is just a text box that the theme provides, I can't put php in a textbox

Comment: can you explain further what your problem is. is it on the wyswyg editor you mean?

Comment: I'll look into it, ill get back to you on that, I'll give you an update.

Comment: OP simply wants to know if they should use full (qualified) URL or relative path.  This answer does not satisfy OP's question.